# How to trim a git-svn repository to remove branches and tags WITHOUT re-cloning?

Tags: git, git-svn

If I forgot to only check out the `trunk` of an SVN repository and instead checked out everything, is there any way to trim my git-svn repository afterwards **without** re-cloning it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to prune the remaining branches that are not master? Is this an SVN repository or a Git repository?

Comment: @BrianaSwift: Here's another way to say it: I ran `git svn clone <repo>` and got the whole repo cloned locally. Now I want to achieve the effect of `git svn clone <repo>/trunk` from what I already have **without** actually having to re-run `clone` the remote repository all over again from scratch. How do I do it?

Comment: Once git is tracking files (or versions of files on branches), they can't ever really be _untracked_. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @BrianaSwift: I don't know precisely what `git svn clone` is doing under the hood when I tell it to only clone the `trunk`, so I don't know if what you're saying is equivalent to what I'm trying to do or not. But I'm trying to do is literally what I wrote in the above comment, which should be pretty unambiguous? Unless my syntax is wrong...

Comment: What's the purpose of removing branches and tags? Do you want to free up some disk space, or you want to stop receiving updates for branches? In the latter case you can use the `svn-remote.<name>.ignore-paths` config key (see the description of `git svn fetch --ignore-paths` at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).

Comment: @Leon: It's huge and obscenely slows down my `git status`.

Comment: So why don't you just do a sparse checkout?

Comment: @Leon: Because I do want the history to still be in the repo?

Comment: Sparse checkout will keep the history and should speed `git status` up

Comment: Do you confuse sparse checkout with shallow clone?

Comment: @Leon: Oh, oops, I think I did. How do I do a sparse checkout with `git-svn`? Would it still work correctly if I did? I'm worried the "SVN" aspect of the repo might break...

Comment: I cannot tell for sure but I don't think that it will break. Sparse checkout should only affect the index and work tree, whereas, in my understanding, the SVN aspect should apply to the repository proper.

Comment: For sparse checkout read this: http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/

Comment: @Leon: Okay, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `git filter-branch` with a `subdirector-filter` to change the repository history so that only trunk changes are included and at the root of the directory like `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter trunk`.

And you also have to change the commit messages (e. g. in the same `filter-branch` run with `msg-filter` to include the `/trunk` in the `git-svn` metadata that is stored in the commit messages like `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter trunk --msg-filter 'sed s!/project@!/project/trunk@!'`

Then you have to change the `git` config value `svn-remote.svn.url` in `git config -e` to only sync `trunk` by adding `/trunk` to the end.

You also have to update the git-svn remote ref by `git update-ref refs/remotes/git-svn master`.

Last but not least you need to delete some metadata that will be rebuilt by `git-svn` by deleting `.git/svn/refs/`.

After all this it should be like you desired, I just tried it with a little test repository.

Comment: A little worried as to whether this would break anything, but +1!

Comment: To be honest, I just made this up, so it might miss something. But at least for my little testcase it produce the correct result. The only difference to a clone of only trunk is, that empty commits (e. g. commits that only set properties or add empty directories) are not in the result tree while they were with the trunk clone command.

Comment: Well, I upvoted, but I'm hesitant about accepting given that I'm not sure it's not missing anything... for my case I just ended up re-cloning the repo so I didn't end up using this at all. :\

Comment: It doesn't miss anything in my example repo, so unless you have proof there is something handled incorrectly, please consider accepting so that others are more confident to use the answer. They can still downvote or comment if it does *not* work correctly.